# Opacity does not working on Ionic 3

Tags: css, ionic3, background-image

How to put a dark opacity only in the background image? Below is the `CSS` code

```
.loginPage{
   background:url('../../assets/icon/backgroundlogin') no-repeat center;
   background-size:cover;
   background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

And here, my `html` code

```
<ion-content padding class="loginPage">
// Here is my content
</ion-content>
```

[image: And here is my image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [multiple `background`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds), using commas`,`  something like:

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0,.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), url('../../assets/icon/backgroundlogin') no-repeat center
```

Here is a basic example:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0,.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEEPy.jpg) no-repeat center / cover
}
```

Comment: I tried that way too, but it did not work out.

Comment: see updated answer, I was thinking using in another way , but for full cover has to be done with `linear-gradient` to fake rgba opacaity